# How do you get the IP address of a Google Cloud Run server?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I have a K8s cluster that should whitelist a Cloud Run server, so I would like to know the IP address or IP range of the Cloud Run server.

Comment: Do you manage the Cloud Run service?

Comment: Cloud Run doesn't run in "particular servers". So you can't deterministically know IP address for connections originating from Cloud Run containers. This might change in the future, but this isn't a thing for now. Consider implementing another authorization mechanism instead of IP firewalling.

Answer (score 2):

As found here:

https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-faq#is-there-a-way-to-get-static-ip-for-outbound-requests

> **Is there a way to get static IP for outbound requests?**
>
> Currently not, since Cloud Run uses a dynamic serverless machine pool by Google and its IP addresses cannot be controlled by Cloud Run users.
>
> However, there is a workaround to route the traffic through a Google Compute Engine instance by running a persistent SSH tunnel inside the container and making your applications use it.

Comment: [Patrick Howard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13843500/patrick-howard) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65257295/12695027) saying "Not sure if you've already seen this, but FWIW this has been updated" and "This feature is still in Beta for Cloud Run."